# Permission denied when trying to POST information to some other page?

Tags: javascript, forms, post

I am using the following to POST information, and when I am creating the form element, I get an exception: "Permission denied".

```
var newWindow = window.open('', '_blank', 'alwaysRaised=yes,toolbars=no, menubar=no, location=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, status=yes,left=10000, top=10000, width=10, height=10, visible=none', '');

var tempFormElement = newWindow.document.createElement('form');
tempFormElement.method = 'post';
tempFormElement.action = urlToOpen;

var tempInputElement;
tempInputElement = newWindow.document.createElement('input');
tempInputElement.setAttribute('TPLInfo', JSON.stringify(linkageInfo));
tempFormElement.appendChild(tempInputElement);
tempFormElement.submit();

newWindow.document.body.removeChild(tempFormElement);
newWindow.close();
```

Please suggest.

Comment: @mplungjan — There are no restrictions on what you can set the action to be (although it could cause problems for the last two lines), and the OP says the error is two lines before that anyway.

Comment: After adding in data for the missing variables, I could not reproduce the problem. The only error was in trying to to remove tempFormElement from the body (because you never added it to the body).

Comment: You were able to open a window at pos 10000 that was smaller than 10px from a web server?

Comment: @mplungjan — Ish. The window got moved back within the bounds of the desktop, but all the code ran: http://jsbin.com/pohisezo/1

Comment: I can run your code in IE8 but I do not see an output. Can you take the URL from my fiddle please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Due to security restrictions, most browsers nowadays will not allow you to create a new window **outside the view port or smaller than 100x100**
2. you do not need to open new windows - instead use AJAX
3. If you cannot use AJAX because of urlToOpen is on another domain, you could not have closed the window or removed the tempform element anyway.
4. you could not do that on the same origin either since it is no longer there after submission
5. there is no valid property of an input element called TPLInfo

So I suggest - if you can:

Ajax using jQuery

```
$.post(urlToOpen,{"TPLInfo":JSON.stringify(linkageInfo)});
```

or if not on same domain (plain JS) :

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/M7Tb7/)

```
var newWindow;
var urlToOpen = "....";
function perform() {
      if (!newWindow) { 
        alert("Sorry, you must allow popups");
        return;
      }
      var tempFormElement = newWindow.document.createElement('form');
      tempFormElement.method = 'post';
      tempFormElement.action = urlToOpen;
      var tempInputElement;
      tempInputElement = newWindow.document.createElement('input');
      tempInputElement.setAttribute("name","TPLInfo");
      tempInputElement.value = JSON.stringify({"a":"1"});
      tempFormElement.appendChild(tempInputElement);
      newWindow.document.body.appendChild(tempFormElement);
      tempFormElement.submit();
}
window.onload=function() {
    document.getElementById("but").onclick=function() {
//   var parms = "alwaysRaised=yes,toolbars=no,menubar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,left=10000,top=10000,width=10,height=10,visible=none";
      // valid parms, yes I know you want to hide and close but nope.
      var parms = "scrollbars,resizable,status,left=10000,top=10000,width=100,height=100";

      newWindow = window.open('', '_blank',parms);
      setTimeout(perform,500);  // give IE time to get over opening
  }
}
```